# Is it possible to use GPU hardware acceleration using Nvidia GPU?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gpu, cpu-usage, youtube

I wonder if it is possible to somehow run gpu acceleration in Linux Mint. My CPU is used over 50% while scrolling sites or watching YT or FHD video with VLC. When I'm watching YT on one monitor and scrolling some site on the other one, YT film video loses frames and CPU usage goes to 100%. I was looking and trying some solutions (turn on/off hardware acceleration in chrome, change chrome flags, trying nouveau drivers), but nothing helped. Also when I'm watching some more dynamic YT videos I can see many graphic glitches.

Is there any solution for that? I want to move from Windows to Linux, but with that problems it can by very difficult for me.

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3. My GPU driver is Nvidia driver 390. Also I'm using google chrome browser (also tried with firefox, no difference).

My PC specs:

- CPU: Intel i5 2500K (no OC)
- RAM: 16 GB DDR3 1600
- GPU: Nvidia GF 1070

Comment: Hard to say from this. Usually you don't need to do anything, hw acc is enabled by default. All you need is the latest drivers for your card. You can try different drivers though. Nvidia has open source (noveau, will be in your software repo) and proprietary drivers (download directly from nvidia.com).

Answer (score 1):

Read this article: https://www.pcsuggest.com/chromium-hardware-accelerated-video-decoding-linux/

It explains very well how to proceed.

I'm not sure with Linux Mint, but I can confirm it works in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.